# Allow extensions using Debugger for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using the extension **Debugger For Chrome** on **Visual Studio Code** to debug JavaScript client code

As you know, **it starts a new Chrome instance, without any extension.**

Is there a way to allow Chrome extensions on that instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find how to do what I asked. But a workaround that worked for my problem is to attach the debugger to an opened instance of Chrome.

So I can use extensions when debugging on Visual Studio Code.

In the file `./.vscode/.launch.json` I edited the object that has `"type": "chrome"`

From:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Meteor: Chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

To:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Meteor: Chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/*",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "port": 9222
},
```

And add to the Chrome shortcut the **remote-debugging-port** parameter as you can see in the following image:

[image: Chome remote debugging port]

Once this is done, you have to open Chrome from your modified shortcut, go to the URL that you want to debug (The same that is on the URL value) and then attach the debugger on Visual Studio Code clicking on Start Debugging.

Note that:

- The port of the JSON and the port of the Chrome shortcut must match.
- I edited the URL value from  `"http://localhost:3000/"` to  `"http://localhost:3000/*"`. The asterisk is because when you open your project, maybe it will redirect you to and URL like `"http://localhost:3000/dashboard"` or something similar. So when you try to attach the debugger it will no match. The asterisk says to the debugger that the last part of the URL could be anything.